# mybatis @MapperScan not working

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to set up the Java config for MyBatis & the @MapperScan does not appear to be accomplishing anything.  Note, I can get the application to work with XML config.

What am I missing?  The com.test.mapper package definitely exists & has a file/iterface called TestMapper.  The corresponding xml is in the correct location in the resources folder.

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field templateMapper in
>   com.test.TestController required a
>   bean of type 'com.test.mapper.TestMapper' that
>   could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.test.mapper.TestMapper' in your
>   configuration.

**Autowired that is failing**

```
@Autowired
TestMapper _testMapper;
```

**config**

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("com.test.mapper")
public class AppConfig {

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {

     SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
     try {
       dataSource.setDriverClass(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class);
       //dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
       dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=db1;integratedSecurity=true;");

     } catch (Exception e) {

     }
     return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
     return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
   }

   @Bean
   public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
     SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();

     sqlSessionFactoryBean.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.test.domain");

     sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
     return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this.  My issue wasn't with Mybatis.  It was with Spring.  [This link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) to the Spring docs says to "...locate your main application class in a root package above other classes".

I had not done that.  Once I moved application class ( annotated with SpringBootApplication) then the @MapperScan annotation worked.